# Execute a jar at console from another folder

Tags: console

I'm writing a Python script which at certain point needs to launch a jar file. So I was thinking about making a system call with command:

```
'./myjarfile.jar'
```

The problem is that I have that jar in a different folder. So I tried:

```
'./home/users/myuser/myfolder/myjarfile.jar'
```

which doesn't work at console. Also tried using java binary:

```
'java /home/users/myuser/myfolder/myjarfile.jar'
```

which doesn't work either.

Any help?

Comment: I think your second command is wrong. I tried `/home/users/myuser/myfolder/myjarfile.jar` and it works. If I try `./home/users/myuser/myfolder/myjarfile.jar` I get an error message `zsh: datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden: ./home/users/myuser/myfolder/myjarfile.jar` which means that the file was not found.

Comment: I [answered your question](http://askubuntu.com/a/249868/23878). If it's right, than please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your second command is wrong. I tried:

```
/home/users/myuser/myfolder/myjarfile.jar
```

and it works. If I try:

```
 ./home/users/myuser/myfolder/myjarfile.jar
```

I get an error message:

```
zsh: datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden: ./home/users/myuser/myfolder/myjarfile.jar
```

which means that the file was not found.

The third command is also wrong. Try `java -jar /home/users/myuser/myfolder/myjarfile.jar`